# How can I make two packages run in Parallel and the classes inside those packages to run in Sequentially using TestNg

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

Please help me. I have created two packages which contains different classes. My purpose is to run this two packages parallel (like two browsers will open and it should run parallely) and the classes inside those packages should run Sequentially. 
I tried using two xml for this. Like shown below, but it's still running  sequentially:

***** testng1.xml*******

```
*<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<suite name="My HDFS suite">
<test name="Test_HDFS" parallel="false">
<classes>
<class name="com.testSuites.HDFS.MySql_Workflow" /> 
<class name="com.testSuites.HDFS.DB2_Workflow" /> 
<class name="com.testSuites.HDFS.Oracle_Workflow" /> 
</classes>
</test>
</suite>*
```

***** testng2.xml******

```
*<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<suite name="My HIVE suite">
<test name="Test_HIVE" parallel="false">
<classes>
<class name="com.testSuites.HIVE.MySql_DataIngestion_Workflow" /> 
<class name="com.testSuites.HIVE.DB2_Workflow" /> 
<class name="com.testSuites.HIVE.Oracle_Workflow" /> 
</classes>
</test>
</suite>*
```

***** suite of Suite****

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<suite name="suite of suites" parallel="suite-file" thread-count="2">
<suite-files parallel="true">
<suite-file path="testng1.xml" />
<suite-file path="testng2.xml" />
</suite-files>
</suite>
```

Please tell me what I am doing wrong in this xml? Since its not running in parallel as expected. 
 All my classes have @BeforeClass and @AfterClass:

- @BeforeClass - I am opening my browser
- @After class - I am closing my browser

So each in class when it runs it opens browser and then closes after that class is over.

I want my *com.testSuites.HDFS* and *com.testSuites.HIVE* to run in parallel and the classes inside should run sequentially. Kindly suggest a solution for me.

Comment: Hi could somebody please help me

Answer (score 1):

i think testNg annotation can help you with that. you can use @dependsonGroups or @dependsonclass.
you can try in your own way.

thanks